# R over(): Erreur : identicalCRS(x, y) is not TRUE but when checked CRS are the same

Tags: r, projection

I have a problem to use the over function.

```
CRS.new=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")

proj4string(ANFR_IDF)=CRS.new

proj4string(parti)=CRS.new

test=over(pc100m,parti)
> Erreur : identicalCRS(x, y) is not TRUE

crs(parti)
> CRS arguments:
 +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 

crs(ANFR_IDF)
> CRS arguments:
 +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 

test=over(parti,pc100m)
>Erreur : identicalCRS(x, y) is not TRUE
```

I don't understand what is hapenning. Any idea?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in my program when I used the same projection string.

I added "+init=epsg:4326" component at the beginning of the projection string and noticed some transformation operations (package concaveman in my case) remove this component, so identicalCRS function returned FALSE.

Try to include "+init" component in your projection string.